# Skip recompile when test single Class with Maven

Tags: java, maven, testing, ant, maven-lifecycle

I was writing very long time test driven code with Ant. A while ago decided to give maven a try. Now I'm very comfortable with maven, in special with dependency management.

But now I'm wondering if its possible to test a single class **without** recompiling the whole project every time I made changes to code in this single class. But also if I just want to run the tests in this single class, without any changes, all phases within maven must be finished to reach test phase.

That means all steps from validate and compile, for a test execution in **single class** that neither has been changed.

Is there a common way to specify the point of execution. Just tested ant with this scenarion, takes just 0.8 seconds, but maven consumes about 2 seconds.

Thanks!
Adem